# What is the point of naming a function in a Functional Interface?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I'm reading about Functional Interfaces in Java in [this tutorial](http://java2practice.com/2014/03/16/java-8-functional-interface-example/)

Here is the specific code that is bothering me:

```
public interface FunctionalInterfaceTest{
void display();
}
//Test class to implement above interface
public class FunctionInterfaceTestImpl {
      public static void main(String[] args){
     //Old way using anonymous inner class
     FunctionalInterfaceTest fit = new FunctionalInterfaceTest(){
        public void display(){
           System.out.println("Display from old way");
        }};
     fit.display();//outputs: Display from old way
     //Using lambda expression
     FunctionalInterfaceTest newWay = () -> {System.out.println("Display from new Lambda Expression");}
        newWay.display();//outputs : Display from new Lambda Expression
     }
}
```

I don't understand. What is the point of having a function called `display()`. It doesn't do anything and is never defined. Yes I understand that when you call the single method in a Functional Interface, it executes the code in the lambda expression that was created in it.

But here's my question; if all functional interfaces essentially just run lambda expressions, then why not just save us the time of naming the single method, and just make it permanently `exe()`? What is the point of offering the Functional Interface syntax and customization if it adds almost nothing. A far better syntax for me would be:

```
@FunctionalInterface MyInterface

MyInterface mine = () -> {System.out.print("Mine!!")}
mine.exe();
```

This is much more standard, shorter and easier to understand.

Is this a brilliant idea or am I missing something?

Comment: Standard according to *what*?  In all honestly, what has been accomplished here?  You've substituted one self-defined function name for another self-defined function name.

Comment: You seem to be completely missing the point. Functional interfaces are just interfaces with one method, and as such have existed far before Java 8 and lambdas (Runnable, Comparable, Comparator, etc etc).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the point of having a function called display(). It doesn't do anything and is never defined.

It's *still* an interface at heart, and it's still subject to the same wonky rules that an interface would be if you *weren't* using lambdas.

The `display` method could be defined on a concrete class in the exact same manner...

```
public class Concrete implements FunctionalInterfaceTest {

    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Displayed!  W00t!");
    }
}
```

...and we would have done the *exact* same amount of work:  we have an interface which only generates side effects.  This is not desirable.

The real power of this comes in when you want to actually do [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) operations on objects or primitives, but you don't want to define concrete classes just to specify what those operations actually are.

Let's suppose we wanted a functional interface to give us the difference of two `Number`s.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface NumberAdder<T extends Number>  {
    T result (T firstValue, T secondValue);
}
```

I can then use it in this manner:

```
NumberAdder<Integer> numberAdder = (x, y) -> x + y;
NumberAdder<Long> longAdder = (x, y) -> x + y;
// From (x, y) -> x.add(y);, the below is shortened to a method reference
NumberAdder<BigInteger> bigIntAdder = BigInteger::add;
```

It's by and large syntactic sugar for the subclassing - anonymous or not - that would have to happen with the interface.  Instead, I can define the contract once and define the behavior in whatever scenario/context I need it to be in.

```
System.out.println(numberAdder.result(10, 20));
System.out.println(longAdder.result(172893791273L, 979789123L));
System.out.println(bigIntAdder.result(BigInteger.valueOf(172917298179821L), BigInteger.valueOf(17232891L)));
```

**It is still your responsibility to define the behavior.** You could easily write this:

```
NumberAdder<BigInteger> bigIntAdder2 = BigInteger::divide;
```

...and that would still be *just fine* with the interface.  You need to be careful that your intended use isn't abused when it comes time to actually implement it.

Don't treat lambdas as anything that they aren't.  By and large, you're replacing anonymous classes with a lambda expression.  If you want to get fancy with it you're more than welcome to, but don't assume that every functional interface follows the same conventions between them.